# How to report a contradictory opinion issued in a debate?

Tags: phrase-request

Consider you are asked to summarize a discussion between two students where they are not on the same page about an issue. I came up with two sentences.

First, a sentence with non-defining relative clause:

> 1. The man, **who disagrees with the woman**, believes that universities should not raise the tuition fees.

I don't want to use such clauses. I want to use phrases implying the same thing. For instance:

> 2. The man, **in contrast to the woman**, believes that universities should not raise the tuition fees.

---

In this context, I came up with these phrases:

- as opposed to
- in (sharp) contrast  to
- on the contrary

However, based on [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101781/whats-the-difference-between-on-the-contrary-and-in-contrast/101786#101786) and [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+opposed+to), I think neither would be idiomatic.

---

Does the sentence #2 make sense?

Would you suggest some phrases? Please note that, I want to put that phrase **between two commas**. *I guess (I don't know) that is called apposition which is somehow similar to non-defining relative clauses- first example.*

Comment: The man, unlike the woman, believes that ...

Comment: "on the contrary to" is a mashup of "on the contrary, ..." and "contrary to". It is not viable.  **as opposed to** is fine. It could follow **believes**. The man believes, as opposed to the woman, that...."

Comment: @TRomano Ah- I will correct that, give me a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The man, on the contrary, believes..." works fine, as long as the previous sentence describes the woman's position.

"The man, on the other hand, believes..." also works this way.

"The man, meanwhile, believes..." also works this way.

"The man, unlike the woman, believes..." works fine on its own, and does not require the previous sentence to describe the woman's position. (Side note - this is actually an example of the situation described by the idiom "the exception proves the rule" - by stating an exception to something, you prove the existence of the thing).

Comment: Thank you. The point is that I do not want to mention the woman's opinion. That helps me to be save more space in writings or saving more time when making time-limited speeches. I think @Tromano's suggestion is also very helpful.